# ArangoDB Windows Idle CPU Load

Tags: arangodb

I have installed arangodb and apart form adding about 10 documents via the console, and otherwise just briefly play with it, it has used over 30 minutes of cpu time in the last 7 days, why is it so high?

I also have MySQL installed, and actively being used (8k+ queries) and its cpu time is less than 30 seconds.

Is this just a problem/issue relating to the windows port, or is this 'normal'.

I see random spikes to 5~10% cpu when watching the process in task manager, even though it is answering no queries.

Edit: Running arango 2.7.2 x64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ArangoDB has 3 jobs that will periodically cause CPU usage:

- the database internal statistics jobs
- the V8 javascript engine with its garbage collection
- The [Foxx services](https://www.arangodb.com/foxx/) with their [Foxx-queues](https://docs.arangodb.com/Foxx/Develop/Queues.html)

You can disable the 3rd via the `arangod.conf`:

```
[server]
foxx-queues = false
```

This will make some of the statistics in the webinterface unavailable.

If you leave a browser with the webinterface open, this will also permanently use resources on the arangod process.

Comment: Server statistics can also be turned off by setting `disable-statistics = true` in the same config section `[server]`. This may also help.

Comment: It does seem very very aggressive compared to other database engines, but i guess it is infact alot more than merely a database engine at the end of the day.

Comment: You are right, there is more going on in the server due to the fact that the JavaScript engine is embedded and allows to execute regular things (foxx-queues). Furthermore, in a cluster setup there is even more going on to monitor liveness. If, in the single server setup, you switch off the foxx-queues and the statistics and do not leave the web interface open, I would imagine that the CPU activity is very low indeed, comparable to what a single server MySQL shows.